# Как привязать select2 к классу который меняется после перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: jquery, select2

Есть такой код:

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
// In your Javascript (external .js resource or <script> tag)
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.category-22').select2();
});
</script>
```

На сайте после каждой перезагрузки страницы класс category-22 постоянно меняется то category-222 то category-321 а мне к этому инпуту нужно привязать плагин select2. Как решить данную проблему?
Я подумал может быть возможно через клик получить значение класса элемента и его же подставить к плагину но я плохой программист и не знаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Этот класс единственный у инпута?

Comment: так выглядит select: <select name="category" id="question-category-801" class="form-control">

Comment: 1. Это `select`, а не `input`. 2. Класса не вижу такого, вижу ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [селектор по атрибуту](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Attribute_selectors):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('[id^="question-category-" i]').select2();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало!